# how to upload event create photo of in my app using facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi
I want to upload a event photo in my app ie event create and also in my database the following is my code:
**HTML file:**

```
<tr>
    <td class="style6 style1 style8"><span class="style30">Add Event Photo </span></td>
    <td colspan="4"><input name="userfile" type="file" class="style28" id="userfile"  size="50" height="25" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input name="image" type="image" src="img_2.gif" alt="submit form" border="0" /></td>
</tr>
```

now the php code to upload:

```
if (isset($_POST['eventtitle'])&& $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0){
$fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
$fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

$fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
$content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
$content = addslashes($content);
fclose($fp);

if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
    $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
}
mysql_query("INSERT INTO  event values('$uid','$eventID','$newDate','$newtime','$newDate2','$newtime1','$name','$location','$street','$city','$fileName', '$fileSize', '$fileType','$content','$description')");
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

`name`, `size`, `type` and `content` are fields for the image.

Comment: 1) your first `if` statement is not closed properly 2) you didn't use the website formatting 3) your question is not clear.   PUT more effort on you questions to get answers. and finally welcome to SO!

Comment: this data is to store the image in database how can i upload the image in facbook create event .ya i know the loop closes after msql_close($con);.plz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've written a tutorial about this two days ago: [How To: Create Facebook Events Using Graph API – Advanced](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-create-facebook-events-using-graph-api-advanced/59/)

Sample code:

```
<?php
$app_id = "APP_ID";
$app_secret = "APP_SECRET";
$my_url = "REDIRECT_URL"; // mainly this should be the same URL to THIS page

$code = $_REQUEST["code"];

if(empty($code)) {
    $auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
    . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
    . "&scope=create_event";
    echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
}

$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
. $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
. "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
. "&code=" . $code;
$access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

if( !empty($_POST) && (empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['start_time']) || empty($_POST['end_time'])) ) {
    $msg = "Please check your inputs!";
} elseif(!empty($_POST)) {
    $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/events?" . $access_token;
    $params = array();
    // Prepare Event fields
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
        if(strlen($value))
            $params[$key] = $value;

    // Check if we have an image
    if( isset($_FILES) && !empty($_FILES['picture']['name']) ) {
        $uploaddir = './upload/';
        $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['picture']['name']);
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
            $params['picture'] = "@" . realpath($uploadfile);
        }
    }
    $params['method'] = "post";

    // Start the Graph API call
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $decoded = json_decode($result, true);
    curl_close($ch);
    if(is_array($decoded) && isset($decoded['id'])) {
        // Event created successfully, now we can
        // a) save event id to DB AND/OR
        // b) show success message AND/OR
        // c) optionally, delete image from our server (if any)
        $msg = "Event created successfully: {$decoded['id']}";
    }
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Create An Event</title>
<style>
label {float: left; width: 100px;}
input[type=text],textarea {width: 210px;}
#msg {border: 1px solid #000; padding: 5px; color: red;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php if( isset($msg) ) { ?>
<p id="msg"><?php echo $msg; ?></p>
<?php } ?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
    <p><label for="name">Event Name</label><input type="text" name="name" value="a" /></p>
    <p><label for="description">Event Description</label><textarea name="description"></textarea></p>
    <p><label for="location">Location</label><input type="text" name="location" value="" /></p>
    <p><label for="">Start Time</label><input type="text" name="start_time" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>" /></p>
    <p><label for="end_time">End Time</label><input type="text" name="end_time" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d")+1, date("Y"))); ?>" /></p>
    <p><label for="picture">Event Picture</label><input type="file" name="picture" /></p>
    <p>
        <label for="privacy_type">Privacy</label>
        <input type="radio" name="privacy_type" value="OPEN" checked='checked'/>Open&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="radio" name="privacy_type" value="CLOSED" />Closed&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="radio" name="privacy_type" value="SECRET" />Secret&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Create Event" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I recommend you read the tutorial and the previous one linked in the same article for more information.